# mailer authentication error in Rails 3.2 with gmail or SendGrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail, actionmailer

I'm trying to set up mailing from a very simple Rails 3.2 app. Tried Gmail, tried SendGrid. Getting same error.

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in UsersController#create
530-5.5.1 Authentication Required
```

Here's my section of environments/development.rb

```
# Care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

# Change mail delivery to either :smtp, :sendmail, :file, :test
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "signaldesign.net",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["gmailusername"],
  password: ENV["gmailpassword"]
}
```

Here's my users_controller

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

I'm stumped. None of the suggestions I've found online are making a difference.

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the username and password?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have them in that config file when I'm testing on localhost. Just changed them for this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I finally resorted to just deleting things and trying again.

I changed my smtp_settings username and password from:

```
user_name: ENV["gmailusername"],
password: ENV["gmailpassword"]
```

to

```
user_name: "gmailusername",
password: "gmailpassword"
```

Comment: It sounds like you never set the environment variables on your server. If you're using heroku, they add the SendGrid ones for you once you add the addon

Comment: @swift Yeah, I finally figured that out. I decided, for now, to keep trying to get gmail to work. I've got environment variables in heroku config, but I'm having trouble getting heroku to use them when actionmailer makes the call. I need to make an initializer but I'm having trouble hooking it all together. Any tips?

Comment: if you run `heroku config` do you see your credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile the [gem dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) changed its implementation. You can now use your `ENV` settings to initialize the `ActionMailer`. I verified this with `dotenv v.0.7.0`. Make sure you load the environment variables. Autoloading has been **removed** from the gem. Read [here](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#sinatra-or-plain-ol-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the domain to `localhost.localdomain`

Comment: Nope. That didn't change anything.