# Why am I unable to send an email with pow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rack-pow

I have a rails project which sends an email using an ActionMailer. This seems to work fine with 'rails server' on localhost:3000 but when I use pow, I get authentication error messages from the smtp server. I'm guessing this has something to do with environment variables. Here is the config code

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 address: "smtp.gmail.com",
 port: 587,
 domain: "railscasts.com",
 authentication: "plain",
 enable_starttls_auto: true,
 user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
 password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

I'm on Mountain Lion.

Thanks

Comment: domain: "railscasts.com" might have something to do with it

Comment: I'll try removing it but just to note again, rails server works fine, only pow doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pow loads environment variables from checking two files in the application root

1. .powrc
2. .powenv

I created the .powrc file using the touch command, then added my environment variables

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME=username
export GMAIL_PASSWORD="my password"
```

I then restarted the worker for the app this way:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

E-mails now work!

Comment: For my and anyone elses reference (because it was not so simple to understand for me at the beginning): Use the variables in .powrc as Tushar described, but then in your environment file (e.g. development.rb) use `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` as your username (or whatever you call your variable). Same goes for your password. Probably I'm just lame and this is clear to everyone, but it may be useful for beginners :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a different suggestion:

In dev, just use [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener). It's more useful in that context than actually sending emails, anyway.

In production, use [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) and not GMail. SendGrid is awesome and really easy to set up.

Comment: Letter opener looks cool. However, SendGrid is too heavy for my needs. Mine is just a hobby project basically.

Answer (score 1):

As blamattina has suggested, it may have something to do with your domain in your configuration file! According to the [example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail) given by Ruby on Rails Guides:

The correct, Gmail compatible configuration looks like this:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => 'baci.lindsaar.net',
:user_name            => '<username>',
:password             => '<password>',
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Your `domain` is set to `railscasts.com`. Unless that's your website, my guess is that this domain is not correct. In fact, it is [apparently optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379950/gmail-smtp-with-rails-3) as well.

This StackOverflow details that a plugin was once necessary, but is no longer needed if you're using Rails 3.2 or higher. A comment below the top answer in the article details that the `domain` is optional.

Update: Based on the error you described, it looks like you're hitting an authentication error! This may be because of your login credentials [not properly registering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302900/mailer-authentication-error-in-rails-3-2-with-gmail-or-sendgrid).

This user is asking in the context of using Heroku, but the error is the same. If your app works properly with the Rails server, but not on Pow, it's a server-side setup issue. The solution involves needing to properly set your `ENV` (environment) variables to work with your server.

Comment: I tried getting rid of the domain and it still doesn't work. The specific error message is this
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in SubscribersController#send_email

530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Comment: This may answer your problem! If it's an authentication error you're encountering, it may be because of your login credentials not properly registering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302900/mailer-authentication-error-in-rails-3-2-with-gmail-or-sendgrid 

This user is asking in the context of using Heroku, but the error is the same. It may involve needing to properly set your `ENV` (environment) variables. First, try setting the Username and Password without the ENV prefixes.